# value of pointer to a char array vs plain char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having a hard time understanding where I can use a pointer to an array,
e.g: `char (*a)[10];`.
So two basic questions.

1. Please give me a simple example of how just a pointer to an array can be used in C code.
2. Why would one use it as apposed to just declaring a variable as a pointer and then incrementing/decrementing the address after that point.

Comment: so many possible duplicates of this question laying in our database that I don't know where to start. Use the search box. :)

Comment: I think you're going at things backwards. Instead of trying to find a problem that could be solved with type X, you normally start with a problem and figure out how to solve it...

Comment: I think you're all missing the point.  The OP is asking why the syntactic sugar of brackets is better than simply having a char pointer which happens to point to an array.

Comment: I've changed the title to hopefully draw out the second point of the OP's question a bit better.  Feel free to roll it back if I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a database query that returns a set of strings.  Further, say that you know that these strings are no longer than 9 characters in length.  Only, you don't know how many elements are in the set returned by the query.

```
char (*a)[10] = malloc( NumRecords * sizeof *a );
if ( a == NULL )
{
  /* Handle error appropriately */
  return EXIT_FAILURE; /* Naive */
}

for ( i = 0 ; i < NumRecords ; ++i )
{
  assert(strlen(DbRecordSet[i]) < 10);
  strcpy(a[i], DbRecordSet[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: how to print the elements of an array of `num_row` rows and 3 columns:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ROW(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

// print elements of an array of num_row rows and 3 columns
void print(int (*a)[3], size_t num_row)
{
    size_t num_col = sizeof *a / sizeof **a;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_col; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    int b[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

    print(a, NUM_ROW(a));
    print(b, NUM_ROW(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The drawback to this is that `print` will only work with Nx3 arrays; if you want to print out an Nx4 array, you'd have to use a different function.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you pass an expression with a multi-dimensioned array type to a function, you're going to be working with a pointer to an array:

```
int a[10][20];
foo(a);

void foo(int (*p)[20]) // or int p[][20] 
{ ... }
```